# TypeError: searchsorted requires compatible dtype or scalar, not ndarray (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search, typeerror

I cant apply searchsorted on datetime Index without getting the error:

```
df.index.searchsorted(pd.Series(np.array([df.index[0], df.index.max()])))

>>>TypeError: searchsorted requires compatible dtype or scalar, not ndarray
```

Sample data:

```
x = ['1998-01-07 13:17:00', '1998-01-07 13:18:00', '1998-01-07 13:19:00', '1998-01-07 13:20:00',
     '1998-01-07 13:21:00', '1998-01-07 13:22:00', '1998-01-07 13:23:00', '1998-01-07 13:24:00',
     '1998-01-07 13:25:00', '1998-01-07 13:26:00']
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df.set_index(df.iloc[:, 0], inplace=True)
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index.values)


df.index.searchsorted(pd.Series(np.array([df.index[0], df.index.max()])))
```

Why doesnt it work? (heard it was a bug that was fixed, but somehow it is still there)

How can I make it work?

I need to apply this line in a multiprocessing function, it needs to be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error stated, you are passing a `ndarray` to the `pandas.Series.searchsorted()` which isn't compatible with `df.index` Series which is of data type `pandas.DatetimeIndex`. So, to fix that, you need to adjust the type of the given Series like so:

```
# just change this line
print(df.index.searchsorted(pd.DatetimeIndex([df.index[0], df.index.max()])))
# prints: [0, 9]
```

Comment: "TypeError: searchsorted requires compatible dtype or scalar, not list", what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you probably forgot to cast this list into `pd.DatetimeIndex`. Could you copy my code exactly as it is? It works with me with no problem

Comment: Thanks, bro ... Glad I could help :)